# Where's the project tree-navigation in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation, project

This is just about the worst way I can think of to navigate a project tree - having to click every directory.. every time.

[image]

How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing module. Each project has to have at least one module which will have links to your source code. A project without modules will list only files from the project folder. You can create a new module from existing sources in this menu `File -> New -> Module from Existing Sources...`.

Comment: Ok.  What is this "module" you're referring to?

Comment: Project is just a logical component. It can contain multiple modules but it has to have at least one. A module is basically a parent folder which contains a src folder. I see that you use activator. It has feature that it can generate intellij idea project for you.

Comment: For simple project can be project and module folder the same.